# How would the super() affect the order in MRO?

Tags: python, class, method-resolution-order

## ALL sample codes from JetBrains academy.

If i execute a code like this,

```
#Code sample 1
class Robot:
    def greet(self):
        print("I am a robot")


class Android(Robot):
    def greet(self):
        super().greet()
        print("I am an android")


class PersonalAssistant(Robot):
    def greet(self):
        super().greet()
        print("I am a personal assistant")


class AssistantAndroid(Android, PersonalAssistant):
    def greet(self):
        super().greet()
```

The output is

```
I am a robot
I am a personal assistant
I am an android
None
```

Why the **personal assistant** is printed **before** the **android**?
The MRO of AssistantAndroid is `(<class '__main__.AssistantAndroid'>, <class '__main__.Android'>, <class '__main__.PersonalAssistant'>, <class '__main__.Robot'>, <class 'object'>)`
So first we go to the Android and first found super in Android which make us go to robot then why the code goes to PersonalAssistant instead of execute the next print(I am an android) in Android?

Moreover, could someone teach me where does the **None** comes from?

If the super moved into the next line of print() in the subclass like this.

```
#Code sample 2
class Person:
    def print_message(self):
        print("Message from Person")


class Student(Person):
    def print_message(self):
        print("Message from Student")
        super().print_message()


class Programmer(Person):
    def print_message(self):
        print("Message from Programmer")
        super().print_message()


class StudentProgrammer(Student, Programmer):
    def print_message(self):
        super().print_message()
```

The the output looks in correct order as MRO.

```
jack = StudentProgrammer()
jack.print_message()
# Message from Student
# Message from Programmer
# Message from Person
```

But why the #Code sample 1 execute order so strange?

### ----------

I have added some additional prints here and things are more weird to me..

```
class Robot:
    def greet(self):
        print("Start robot")
        print("I am a robot")
        print("Finish robot")


class Android(Robot):
    def greet(self):
        print("Start Android")
        super().greet()
        print("I am an android")
        print("Finish Android")


class PersonalAssistant(Robot):
    def greet(self):
        print("Start PersonalAssistant")
        super().greet()
        print("I am a personal assistant")
        print("Finish PersonalAssistant")


class AssistantAndroid(Android, PersonalAssistant):
    def greet(self):
        print("Start AssistantAndroid")
        super().greet()
        print("Finish AssistantAndroid")


a = AssistantAndroid()
print('AssistantAndroid', AssistantAndroid.__mro__)
print('Android', Android.__mro__)
print('PersonalAssistant', PersonalAssistant.__mro__)
print("--------------------")
print(a.greet())
```

The output is

```
Start AssistantAndroid
Start Android
Start PersonalAssistant
Start robot
I am a robot
Finish robot
I am a personal assistant
Finish PersonalAssistant
I am an android
Finish Android
Finish AssistantAndroid
None
```

Does this means, when the execute goes to the **level 2 classes( Android and PersonalAssistant)**, it only execute **one line in Android** and **then one line in PersonalAssistant**, then when it executes the **super()** in **Android**?? and it means execute the robot and then after finish the robot, it goes to second line in PersonalAssistant which is also means robot, then it skipped it??, then why finish PersonalAssistant and then finish the Android...I am totally confused..

---

Very appreciate to the answer from @Blckknght

Please refer to his answer I think it explains very well.
Basically, when the Multiple inheritance comes, the only relation you should follow is the MRO order. (The reverse of MRO) So this is why after the `Start Android` follows `Start PersonalAssistant` but not `Start robot` because from the reverse of MRO, the PersonalAssistant becomes the **father** of Android. So the super() in Android will call the the PersonalAssistant but not robot.
Correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Please post this as an answer if possible. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When all of your `greet` methods call `super().greet` before printing their own text, the output will come in the reverse of the MRO (excluding `object`, since it doesn't have a `greet` method).

Think about the call stack, where each method waits for the `super().greet` call to return before going on to `print`. Here's what it looks like, with indentation indicating the depth of the stack:

```
# in AssistantAndroid.greet()...
super().greet() # resolves to Android.greet() when self is an AssistantAndroid

    # in Android.greet()...
    super().greet() # resolves to PersonalAssitant.greet() when self is an AssistantAndroid

        # in PersonalAssistant.greet()...
        super().greet() # resolves to Robot.greet() when self is an AssistantAndroid

            # in Robot.greet(), where there's no super() call
            print("I am a robot")

        # continuing PersonalAssistant.greet()
        print("I am a personal assistant")

    # continuing Android.greet()
    print("I am an android")

# continuing AssistantAndroid.greet(), but there's nothing left to do
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, but sorry I am still confused. So the route is following with the reverse of the MRO but not related with the father class? I mean I thought since the robot is the father of Android so after the super() in Android then it will go to robot...So can I say when MRO comes, the father relation will be revised and the only hierarchy is the MRO, am I correct?

Comment: The MRO is the linear order followed by a chain of `super()` calls (and your printouts happen in the reverse of that). The class hierarchy is used to produce the MRO. It is not used directly by `super()`. If you want to learn more about it, check out [this article](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) that documents the algorithm Python has used since version 2.3. Alas, it's ASCII art diagrams (and snakes!) are a bit hard to read with the site's current wider line spacing, but you can figure them out with some close examination (or by copying and pasting into a text editor).

Comment: Really appreciate, thank you for your kind suggestion.